# Script font indentify

Tags: font-identification

I need to identify the font used on the following image.
The characters in the image are "**jengibre**" without the quoting marks
[image]

Comment: Please crop the image to a sensible size.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  We have some [special requirements for font identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions). Can you review these and [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/136131/edit) to supply the missing information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes take pity on font ID questions (despite our clear guidelines around them) *when it's clear that the font in question will have provided huge challenges* to match in the typical rota of online font match tools - and super-connected script fonts often are a real pain to match with those tools.

This is one of those, without a doubt.

In this instance, one has to take literally the advice shown on *all* the various match-your-font-by-uploading-an-image pages: if your font has connected letters, use image-editing tools to separate them.

That all said - I feel pretty sure I have IDed the correct font.

[image]

[Playscript Font on FFonts](https://www.ffonts.net/Playlist-Script.font?text=jengibr)

Next time, try using an image-editing tool to separate the letter forms - it really does the trick.

Hope that helps.